# mysqlimport with Error 13

Tags: bash, mysqlimport

I use the following script to import data from a `csv` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# show commands being executed, per debug
set -x

# define database connectivity
_db="xxx"
_db_user="xxx"
_db_password="xxx"
_table="movie"

# define directory containing CSV files
_csv_directory="/tmp"

_csv_file='xxxxxx.csv'
_header_columns_string='link,description,duration,thumbnaillink,iframe,tags,category'

# import csv into mysql
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=';' --lines-terminated-by="\n" --columns=$_header_columns_string -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db $_table $_csv_directory/$_csv_file

exit
```

When I execute the script as root via `bash import.sh` I get the following error message:

```
+ _db=mydatabase
+ _db_user=xxx
+ _db_password=xxx
+ _table=movie
+ _csv_directory=/tmp
+ _csv_file=xxxxxx.csv
+ _header_columns_string=link,description,duration,thumbnaillink,iframe,tags,category
+ mysqlimport --local '--fields-terminated-by=;' '--lines-terminated-by=\n' --columns=link,description,duration,thumbnaillink,iframe,tags,category -u xxx -pxxx mydatabase movie /tmp/xxxxxx.csv
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/mydatabase/movie' (Errcode: 2), when using table: movie

+ exit
```

but the database and the table exist.

The `csv` file exists and can be read, the table can be selected and I can manually insert data-rows into the db.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try supplying the `--local` option for `mysqlimport`?

Comment: What are the permissions of that csv file? It needs to be readable by all users on the system. Try either chmod mysql:mysql xxx.csv or chmod 0666 xxx.csv then try again and let us know what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it from inside SQL:

```
load data local infile 'FILENAME.CSV' into table TABLENAME
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines;
```

You run this from the command line or from a shell script like this

```
db='mysql -hX -uX -pX --database=X'
cat MYSCRIPT.SQL | $db
```